# Is a Two sample T-test appropriate for my data?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, t-test, sample-size

sample 1: 9, 13, 30, 23, 34, 43, 39, 113, 4, 5, 11, 17

sample 2: 16, 25, 22, 67, 88, 43, 59, 39, 69, 93, 41, 231

The data is unpaired

I want to calculate a confidence interval for the difference in means between the two samples. Is the Two sample T-test appropriate? Here are the histograms of what my data looks like, I also added one with a log transformation. My data was collected randomly.

[image: sample 1 histogram]

[image: log transformation of sample 1 histogram]

Comment: A t-test is valid when you have independent random samples from normal distributions with the same variance. If you believe each of these is true in your case, then a t-test could be appropriate.

Comment: You have limited samples, we have enough samples to assess if a normal or t distribution is most likely unsuitable. And since you don't know much about this distribution, I guess we cannot use poisson or other test for count data. .. So one option is to avoid parametric test, and use say wilcoxon test (wilcox.test) or a permuation test (see coin package).

Comment: 1. Your observations are integers. What are the original values? Are they counts, for example? 2. In your body test you say you want "a confidence interval for the difference in means", so *no test is appropriate*: a confidence interval is required instead.